# continuous group homomorphism profinite/discrete topology

Tags: topological-groups, profinite-groups

If $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism of groups, $G$ is profinite, and $H$ is an infinite group with discrete topology is $f$ always continuous? If this is too difficult: What if $G=\mathbb Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers?

Comment: How about taking $H = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with the discrete topology and $f$ the identity map?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant that $G$ (profinite), $H$ (discrete) and a group homomorphism $f$ are given. And I was wondering whether $f$ is "automatically" a morphism of topological groups.

Comment: Sorry, unless I misunderstand or am being stupid, I am claiming that the answer is "no, such $f$ is not automatically/always continuous", the counterexample being $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with the profinite topology, $H = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with the discrete topology, and $f = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{Z}_{p}}$.

Comment: oh, I see, you're absolutely right.

Comment: Even $G=\mathbf{Z}_p$ and $H=\mathbf{Q}$ works.